# Is /auth/classroom.topics.readonly a sensitive scope?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-oauth, google-classroom, gsuite-addons

Does anyone know if /auth/classroom.topics.readonly is a sensitive scope?  All my sensitive scopes have a green checkmark icon but topics does not.  The reason I ask is it is giving me problems with OAuth authorization.  Could someone check if their approved consent screen has a green checkbox beside .topics.readonly?

[image]

There is no mention of topics here: https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth
Although it is mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes

I reached out to the OAuth team many times with no answer.  Users cannot move past the OAuth screen and I'm trying to figure out why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct answer is:

**/classroom.topics** and **/classroom.topics.readonly** are **BOTH** **non-sensitive scopes** as shown in this screenshot from OAuth

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is true that `/classroom.topics.readonly` is missing in in the [list](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/auth).

However, if you look at other scopes, you will see that

### it is always the full scopes that are considered `sensitive` , while the `readonly` scope are always the recommended ones.

This makes sense, because full scopes allow you to modify the data, while `readonly` gives only view access.

It is correct that there is no green checkbox next to the `/classroom.topics.readonly` scope in the consent screen.

Comment: /auth/gmail.addons.current.message.readonly is a sensitive scope and it is read only. This is weird because topics.read only is 'authorized' in OAuth and if I list it on the G Suite Market place API config it gives this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60582226/g-suite-marketplace-add-on-oauth-error-400-invalid-request-account-restricted/60963807#60963807.  If I remove it from market place API then it installs fine.

Comment: /classroom.topics (without the readonly) also does not have a green arrow beside it, I'm confused if it is a sensitive scope.

Comment: My answer about `readonly` being not sensitive refers to classroom API. APIs like Gmail or Drive obviously have more restrictions since an email should only be readable for the recipient,while e.g. a classroom topic is visible for all students and domain members. `classroom.topics` without`readonly` is a sensible scope since it allows to create, modify and delete a topic, which only the course teachers are authorised to do.

Comment: I had a look at your other question: if the problem is that only some users get the 400 error -those users should contact GSuite support to understand the issue. Are those users maybe not teachers of the specific course and this do not have the permission to modify a topic?

Comment: classroom.topics without readonly is NOT a sensitive scope, it does not have the green checkmark and I was able to add the scope without verification.  This is unrelated to a specific course as this occurs at the install screen.  It is definitely a setting on the users G Suite account through the admin console but I don't know what it is.